# iOS 14 (Xcode 12) - Sheet Background is white instead of black

Tags: swiftui

I'm fairly new to SwiftUI and I've recently been using Xcode 12.

One pretty annoying thing I've noticed is that when using a sheet, the background is white, whereas in iOS13 (and Xcode 11.7) the background is black. (I'm referring to the background around the Status bar/notch area of the device, not the content below the sheet.)

Has something changed between iOS13 -> iOS14 which affects the sheet?

I'd be ever so grateful if I can be helped here.

Here is the code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showContent = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
                   .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("sadada")
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
                        self.showContent.toggle()
                    })
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showContent) {
                MeowView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Xcode 11.7:**
[image: Xcode 11.7]

**Xcode 12**
[image]

Comment: Do you mean status bar color, sheet background or sheet's parent background?

Comment: @pawello2222 Nope -  the background that appears behind the content view and sheet (the area behind the status bar area and behind the content view that gets pushed back when a sheet is triggered ).

Comment: It is Preview-only effect.